# Calling REST Web Service through java class

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have created a flow which accepts a file from the client and performs some operations. The code looks like this:

```
@Path("/upload")
public class UploadFile {

@POST
@Path("/file")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public InputStream uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedfile,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails) {
        .
        .
}
```

This restful web service is called by an html file like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/upload/file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <p>
    Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
   </p>

   <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
</form>
```

This works totally fine. Could I call this restful web service from a java class. If yes how can it be done.

Comment: Whichever JAX-RS implementation you're using, it probably comes with a client library. Here's the [Jersey Client API documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring RestTemplate object from normal java application to consume your RESTful web service [see this - Spring REST Template](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)